# @Data @AllArgsConstructor [Lombok]

Tags: java, lombok

I have a class person, annoted by two annotations @Data @AllArgsConstructor.
When i try to initialize class person by constructor i have a problem.
No problem in compilation but in runtime i have this error

java: constructor Person in class com.app.net.model.Person cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.List<com.app.net.model.Publication>,java.util.List<com.app.net.model.Comment>
reason: **actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

Anybody has a solution?
thank you

I try to initialize class with constructor with all arguments

Comment: add NoargsAnnotation too

Comment: Show the class in question.

Answer (score 2):

The @AllArgsConstructor annotation creates a constructor for your class where every parameter has to be passed to initialize the class. As suggested, you have to annotate your class with the @NoArgsConstructor if you want to give your class the opportunity to be initialized like this:

```
final var myClass = new MyClass(); // Initialized using the 'NoArgs' constructor
myClass.setProperty(value);
...
```